# (MongoDB Java) $push into array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, nosql-aggregation, jongo

I'm using mongo 2.2.3 and the java driver.
My dilemma, I have to $push a field and value into an array, but I cant seem to figure out how to do this.  A sample of my data:

```
"_id" : 1,
"scores" : [
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 78.97979
    },
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 6.99
    },
    {
        "type" : "quiz",
        "score" : 99
    }
]
```

I can $push in the shell:

```
db.collection.update({_id:1},{$push:{scores:{type:"quiz", score:99}}})
```

but it's when I translate this into java I confuse my self and chuck my keyboard at a wall.

my java code (incomplete and wrong) so far:

```
DBObject find = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);
DBObject push = new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject(
                        "scores", new BasicDBObject()));
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject("scores", new BasicDBObject("type","quiz").append("score",99));
DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$push", listItem);
myCol.update(findQuery, updateQuery);
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i was looking for. i tried somthing similar but i think i put .append in the wrong place.

Comment: i am trying the example but it does not allow me to use "update"..instead asks me for "updateone" with collections  object..

Comment: It's not possible to use 'update'! What's the reason?!

Answer (score 22):

Since `mongodb-driver 3.1.` there is a builder class `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates` with appropriate methods for each update case. In this case this would be:

```
Document score = new Document().append("type", "quiz")
                               .append("score",99);

collection.updateOne(eq("_id", "1"),Updates.addToSet("scores", score));
```

Comment: This is way underrated! The new driver is so much more intuitive.

Comment: Note that the exact equivalent to `$push` is `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.push` which can add duplicates. On the other hand, `Updates.addToSet` is for simulating a set in which if the element already exists, it isn't inserted.

Answer (score 12):

If you're more comforable with the query format of the shell, you may find it's easier to use `JSON.parse` to contstruct your `DBObject` for the `$push`:

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

String json = "{$push:{scores:{type:'quiz', score:99}}}";
DBObject push = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: very nice sir! its like jongo syntax.  really wish i could accept both answers!

Answer (score 6):

Using Jongo, you can do [as in the shell](http://jongo.org/#updating):

```
db.collection.update({_id:1},{$push:{scores:{type:"quiz", score:99}}})
```

Becomes in Java:

```
collection.update("{_id:1}").with("{$push:{scores:{type:#, score:#}}}", "quiz", 99);
```

No fancy DBObject needed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Java driver can simplify this. Use $each instead of $push.

[$each mongodb reference document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each)

Java sample -

```
    BasicDBObject addressSpec = new BasicDBObject();
    addressSpec.put("id", new ObjectId().toString());
    addressSpec.put("name", "one");

    BasicDBObject addressSpec2 = new BasicDBObject();
    addressSpec2.put("id", new ObjectId().toString());
    addressSpec2.put("name", "two");

    List<BasicDBObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(addressSpec); list.add(addressSpec2);

    UpdateResult updateOne = individualCollection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", "5b7c6b612612242a6d34ebb6"), 
            Updates.pushEach("subCategories", list));
```