# Mongo DB add new value to array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to add a value to mongo db inner object with array element without looking at other value. Can some one advice to do this.

Eg: take order collection as,

```
{_id:'ssdeiieirei33',userId: 213828, enrolLment:{"ADMIN":{"TERM1":["COURSE1","COURSE3"]},"STUD":{"TERM2":["COURSE1","COURSE2"]}}}
```

Here I need to add new enrollment(COURSE3) (STUD:{"TERM2":["COURSE3"]}) to enrolLment column with out reading it . 
this should be the result;

```
 {_id:'ssdeiieirei33',userId: 213828, enrolLment:{"ADMIN":{"TERM1":["COURSE1","COURSE3"]},"STUD":{"TERM2":["COURSE1","COURSE2","COURSE3"]}}}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(MongoDB Java) $push into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436542/mongodb-java-push-into-array)

Comment: Yes, you are looking for the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator (or alternatively [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) when you want to avoid duplicates)

Comment: I updated the question with my real collection. sorry about inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) if you don't want duplicates or [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) if duplicates are allowed.

From your wording it seems to me that you want to use `$addToSet`, but please clarify.

**UPDATE**

You should use

```
collection.update({condition},
    {
        $addToSet: {enrolLment.$userName.$Term : "COURSE3"}
    },
callback)
```

Note that I did not test my code. `enrolLment.$userName.$Term` in your case should be `enrolLment.ADMIN.TERM2`. But if you have them in the condition then you can use the `$` notation to access those variables.

Comment: As @JohnnyHK said, your question is not really valid. Do you want to have only counts of items? Then use `{..., items: {'pen':3, 'book':4}}`. That way you don't need any arrays, since you basically have a hash-map.

Comment: I updated the question with my real collection. sorry about inconvenience