# appending data to array in MongoDB-Document using Java Driver 3.4

Tags: java, mongodb, updates, mongo-java-driver

I am using MongoDB Java Driver 3.4 and want to update a document (with id "12") in a Mongo-DB collection. Currently, the document looks as follows:

```
{"id" : "12", "Data" : [{"Author" : "J.K. Rowling", 
                              "Books" : {"Harry Potter 1" : "$15.99", "Harry Potter 2" : "$16.49", "Harry Potter 3" : "$19.49"}},
                             {"Author" : "Philip Roth", 
                              "Books" : {"American Pastoral" : "$12.99", "The Human Stain" : "$39.49", "Indignation" : "$29.49"}}
                            ]}
```

I want to update this document by adding the following object to array "Data":

```
{"Author" : "Stephen King", "Books" : {"Rose Red" : "$12.69", "Faithful" : "$9.49", "Throttle" : "$8.49"}}
```

To this end I wrote the following java code:

```
Document doc = new Document().append("Author", "Stephen King")
                             .append("Data", new Document("Rose Red", "$12.69")
                                            .append("Faithful" : "$9.49")
                                            .append("Throttle" : "$8.49"));                                                                                     

collection.update({"id", "12"}, {$push: {"Data" : doc.toJson()}});
```

The IDE indicates there is something wrong with the last statement (collection.update...) by showing me this:

[image]

I don't know what this error message is supposed to tell me. There is a semicolon at the end of the statement. Does anybody know what's wrong with the java code?

P.S.: This is not a duplicate to 
    [(MongoDB Java) $push into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436542/mongodb-java-push-into-array)
My question relates to Java Driver 3.4. The other question relates to an earlier version with totally different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things incorrect here.

field - Change from `Data` to `Books`

separator - Change from `semicolon` to `comma`

method - Change from `update` to `updateOne` and you can pass `Document` directly.

```
 Document doc = new Document("Author", "Stephen King")
            .append("Books", new Document("Rose Red", "$12.69").append("Faithful", "$9.49").append("Throttle", "$8.49"));

collection.updateOne(new Document("id", "12"), Updates.push("Data", doc));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!