# Adding an element to a list in a MongoDB Document using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a little confused as to how to add an element to an array in an exisiting mongodb document, or why my results are not showing properly and how I expect.

There is only one document in the collection and will only ever be one. The mongo document looks like when I do a `db.collection-name.find.pretty()` command in a mongo session on the command line:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectID("1234567890"),
    "details" : {
        ...
    },
    "calculations" : [
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "total" : 10,
            "mean" : 2.5
        },
        {
            "count" : 2,
            "total" : 20,
            "mean" : 6.4
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add another object to the `calculations` list.

The Java code I am running is based upon [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865878/appending-data-to-array-in-mongodb-document-using-java-driver-3-4) example:

```
// Get the database and collection
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase(dataBaseName);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
Document document = collection.find().first(); // will only ever be one document 

// The object comes in as a Map
Map<String, Object> incomingMap = new HashMap<>();
incomingMap.put("count", 3);
incomingMap.put("total", 4);
incomingMap.put("mean", 7.9);
// convert to a Document
Document newDocument = new Document();
incomingMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        newDocument.append(k, v);
});

// append this to the collection - this is where I am confused
// for this example just hardcoding the _id value for simplicity
collection.updateOne(new Document("_id", "1234567890"), Updates.push("calculations", newDocument));
```

However when I do a `System.out.println(collection.find().first())` in the code after this or `db.collection-name.find.pretty()` in a mongo session the new document has not been added. There are no errors thrown and completes fine.

What I am wondering is

- Is the line `collection.updateOne(new Document("_id", "1234567890"), Updates.push("calculations", newDocument));` correct?
- Has it been added but not been saved - if so how do I save?
- Can I do this at a document level, for example `document.update(new Documen(Updates.push("calculations", newDocument));` or similar?
- I have also tried `collection.findAndUpdateOne(new Document("_id", "1234567890"), Updates.push("calculations", newDocument));` with the same result
- Is how I am getting/hardcoding the document ID incorrect?

Comment: So I have added in a way of getting the document ID instead of hard coding and it works?! Either I had a typo in my ID value or removing my print statement I had for debugging has made it work. 
If anyone could confirm that what I have done is correct that would be good so I can marked it as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have filter condition issue (your `_id` is `ObjectId` type)

```
new Document("_id", ObjectId("1234567890"))`
```

Always make sure your documents updated correctly. Look code fagment:

```
UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(filter, update);
log.info("Update with date Status : " + result.wasAcknowledged());
log.info("Nº of Record Modified : "   + result.getModifiedCount());
```

https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/result/UpdateResult.html